# How to get C++ variable declaration

Tags: c++, regex

I am a newbie in using Regexp

Can anyone please provide required regexp to find all `C++` code lines inside a `C++` source code file used to declare a variable?

Some of the methods variables can be declared could be as mentioned below:

```
int  x;
int  y=9;
int  x,y;
int  x,y=0;
int  x,y=0,c;
short const x=9;
int* x,y,c=null;
short const *x=NULL;
MyObj aobj();
MyObj aobj(x,y);
Myobj * a = dynamic_cast<A *>(b);
String x = "test";
```

Comment: As C and all languages following/extending C syntax (C++, Objective-C, Java, …) are not regular (in the parser sense) this cannot be solved by a regular expression. Only a complete parser (so user defined types are recognised as types) can recognise declarations.

Comment: In case of regexp is there a way to search for string occurrences of below format: word word word;
word word word, word;
word word word = integer, word = word;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will get you started:

```
(int|short|MyObj|String).*(;)
```

breakdown:

1. `(int|short|MyObj|String)` = It will search for any of the listed items.  A `|` can be added to the list along with more options.
2. `.*(;)` = all characters up to the first `;`, basically meaning to the end of the line.

The problem is, there can be many ways to declare a variable.  In your example alone there are 4 (5 if you count for case-sensitivity) ways to declare.  Unless this is just a quick one time thing, I would look for what Richard mentioned about getting a complete parser.  I'm not familiar with `C++` enough to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Is there way that I state that will exclude any of the listed items as per breakdown rule 1?

Comment: If you want to exclude it, just don't put it into the list.  If you want to exclude them some of the time, you would need to identify what the case is to include/exclude and go from there.